# change background of back button to the same as navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to implement a custom image for the navigation bar and buttons on it. I managed to get the correct setup for my nav background using this

[image: this is what happens with the code below]

```
        - (void)customAppearance
{  
    UIImage* NavBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:NavBG forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

but when i try to do something similar for the back button or other button it all just blends together (I can see the words of the back button but no outline for the back button is present)

here is what i have for the back button

```
UIImage *backButtonBG = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 6)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonBG forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and i want to get it looking like this: [image: what the goal is]

Comment: Which file are you trying to change the back button in?  A back button has to be edited in the parent navigation file.  Similar to changing the text of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest way is for you to also tint the navigation bar, because the default is that those bar butons items always use the color of the navigation bar.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

or u can use a more precise color using rgb values

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:val green:val blue:val alpha:1]];
```

Comment: Awesome that is exactly what I needed, so simple too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I created my tinted button using a custom image (see code at the end) Then just set the `leftBarButtonItem` to this button.

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem *)createBarButtonItemWithImage:(UIImage *)normalImage highlightedImage:(UIImage *)highlightedImage
{
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItemToReturn;
    if (normalImage == nil && highlightedImage == nil)
    {
        return barButtonItemToReturn;
    }
    else if (normalImage != nil)
    {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        if (highlightedImage != nil)
        {
            [button setImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, normalImage.size.width, normalImage.size.height)];
        }

        barButtonItemToReturn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    }
    return barButtonItemToReturn;
}
```

When you want to add a target/action, you have to add it via:

```
 [((UIButton*)barButtonItem.customView) addTarget:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You can also use a resizable image, etc